# $G$ is a Group of order $pq$, if $G$ has exactly one subgroup of order $p$ and another with order $q$, then $G$ is cyclic ($p,q$ are prime)

Tags: group-theory

$G$ is a Group of order $pq$, if $G$ has exactly one subgroup of order $p$ and another with order $q$, then $G$ is cyclic ($p,q$ are prime)

Here's what I have so far, I'm not sure if it is correct.

Let $H, K$ be subgroups of $G$
$|H| = p$ 
$|K| = q$

We know that by Lagrange's Theorem: 
$\forall a \in H : |a|=p$ where $a \neq e$ $\Rightarrow H = <a>$ 
Similarly: $\forall a \in K : K = <a>$ 
We also know that: $\forall a \in G : |a| | pq \Rightarrow |a| = p$ or $|a| = q$

$|a| = p \Rightarrow a \in H$ since there is exactly one subgroup of order $p$ 
$|a| = q \Rightarrow a \in K$ for similar reasons

This means every element in $G$ is either in $H$ or $K$, which are both cyclic. That means $G$ is cyclic.

What am I missing here?
Have I made any mistakes and/or is the proof incomplete?

Comment: Your proof seems incomplete. It's not clear how you concluded in the end.

Comment: There is four options when $n\mid pq$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ and primes $p, q$; *viz.*, $n=1$, $n=p$, $n=q$, or $n=pq$.

Answer (score 3):

Possible orders of a non-trivial element of  $G $ are $p $, $q $ or $pq $. If we show the existence of an element of order  $pq$, then we are done.

If $g\in G $ is of order  $p $, then it must be in the subgroup  $H $(why?). Similarly if $g $ has order  $q $, it must be in $K $. Now the number of elements of  $G $ which are neither in $H $ nor in $K $ is equal to  $$\begin{align} pq-(p+q-1) &=p (q-1)-(q-1) \\
&=(p-1)(q-1)\\
&\gt 0.
\end{align}$$

So what can you conclude now?

Comment: May I ask how the equation at the end was derived? Also this shows that there does exist an element with order $pq$ in $G$, but how does that imply $G$ is cyclic?

Comment: @user2965071 Total number of elements is $pq $. Number of elements in $H $ is $p $ and number of elements in $K $ is $q $. But we are double -counting the identity element.  So total number of elements in the $H\cup K $ is $p+q-1$. And for the last question, what's the definition of a cyclic group?

Comment: From what I understand, a definition of a cyclic group is a group with only one generator. I don't see how that is implied, unless my understanding is limited or not correct.

Comment: @user2965071 A cyclic group, by definition, only needs one generator. But that doesn't mean the generator is unique. In general, a cyclic group of order $n $ has $\varphi(n) $ generators, where $\varphi$ is the [Euler's totient function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). I have shown above the existence of a generator and that there are $(p-1)(q-1)$ generators for $G $. Now if you know the properties of totient function, you can see that $\varphi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1) $. Hope this clears everything.

Comment: So is it sufficient enough just to find an element in the group that has the same order as the group itself?

Comment: @user2965071 Yes. ${}{}{}{} $